# Show that $a = \sup \{ a_n | n \in \mathbb{N} \} = \limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

> Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ be an accumulation value of the real sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and an upper bound of the set $\{a_n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Show that
> $$a=\sup\{ a_n | n \in \mathbb{N} \} =  \limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n$$

I think I understand the equation but I do not know how to prove it in a rigorous way.

Comment: Is the limit supposed to be  $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup \{a_m: m \geq n\}$? I am not sure that I understand.

Comment: @leslietownes That's what $\limsup$ usually means.

Comment: It was less clear as originally typeset. If the $\limsup$ is known to exist, call it $L$, I would try to prove that $a \leq L$ and $a \geq L$, perhaps using whatever theorems or definitions are given for $\limsup$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a$ is an upper bound of $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, therefore
\begin{equation}
L\le a\tag1\label{1}
\end{equation}
where $\displaystyle L:=\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n$ (we know that limsup always exists, finitely or infinitely). Also, since $a$ is an accumulation point, for any $\varepsilon>0$, $a-\varepsilon$ has infinite number of points of the sequence above it. Hence,
\begin{align}
&a-\varepsilon\le L\qquad\forall\varepsilon>0\\
\implies &a\le L\tag2\label{2}
\end{align}
From \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}, we get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understood it now.